# How to remove duplicates elements from JSON file using java if else?

Tags: java, json, duplicates, if-statement

This **start** that is found in my codes are from my JSON file. Now that in my JSON file, i have a lot of "start" with the same name. For example in this JSON file, i have duplicates in the start (having both the content as "audi"):

```
{"rel": "AtLocation", "weight": 0.5, "dataset": "/d/dbpedia/en", "sources": ["/s/dbpedia/3.7"], "id": "0209765bf7185615ef242513f61ca0f61efe2a04", "features": ["audi AtLocation -", "audi - curitiba", "- AtLocation curitiba"], "end": "curitiba", "license": "/l/CC/By-SA", "uri": "/a/[AtLocation/,audi/,curitiba/]", "start": "audi", "context": "/ctx/all", "surfaceText": null}

{"rel": "AtLocation", "weight": 0.5, "dataset": "/d/dbpedia/en", "sources": ["/s/dbpedia/3.7"], "id": "5158d1cfce728efb3e42840d166ec06153a3d77d", "features": ["audi AtLocation -", "audi - ingolstadt", "- AtLocation ingolstadt"], "end": "unite_state", "license": "/l/CC/By-SA", "uri": "/a/[AtLocation/,audi/,ingolstadt/]", "start": "audi", "context": "/ctx/all", "surfaceText": null}
```

This is my Java codes:

```
String start = (String) jsonObject.get("start");  
StartVertex startV = new StartVertex(start);  
helloGraphDB.addVertex(startV);
```

I doesnt want it to addVertex 2 times of the same "audi", how do i write the logic if else out?

Thank you.

Comment: what is type of helloGraphDB?

Comment: @AmitD, thank you for your reply! :) it is actually a database thingy.. i linked it to a software called infinitegraph, and to create a Vertex (something like a node), the code is the database name (in this case helloGraphDB) followed by the addVertex(name).

Comment: When you debug, what is the value of your String start?

Comment: @FlorianParain Thank you for your reply! In this situation, the value is "audi". Because the start value in this json file is "audi".

Answer (score 1):

`You can use arraylist to check whether the value already inserted into **addVertex**

Like :

```
ArrayList addedVertex_Val = new ArrayList();
```

```
    String start = (String) jsonObject.get("start");
    boolean shouldInsert = true;

    for (int al_length = 0; al_length < addedVertex_val.size(); al_length++) {
        String val = addedVertex_val.get(al_length).toString();
        if (val.equals(start)) {
            shouldInsert = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (shouldInsert) {
        StartVertex startV = new StartVertex(start);
        helloGraphDB.addVertex(startV);
        addedVertex_Val.add(startV);
    }
```

`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have knock off and will try this codes tomorrow when i am back tmr! Thank you very much! The codes are looking good! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use HashMap instead of array list.

It would be more efficient than linearly checking into ArrayList.

You'll have to just check whether you have a start(eg "audi") in a HashMap,if not you can add it to the Graph and also the HashMap,if it is already there in HashMap you can skip adding it both.

```
String a = "{\"rel\": \"AtLocation\", \"weight\": 0.5, \"dataset\": \"/d/dbpedia/en\", \"sources\": [\"/s/dbpedia/3.7\"], \"id\": \"0209765bf7185615ef242513f61ca0f61efe2a04\", \"features\": [\"audi AtLocation -\", \"audi - curitiba\", \"- AtLocation curitiba\"], \"end\": \"curitiba\", \"license\": \"/l/CC/By-SA\", \"uri\": \"/a/[AtLocation/,audi/,curitiba/]\", \"start\": \"audi\", \"context\": \"/ctx/all\", \"surfaceText\": null}";
        String b = "{\"rel\": \"AtLocation\", \"weight\": 0.5, \"dataset\": \"/d/dbpedia/en\", \"sources\": [\"/s/dbpedia/3.7\"], \"id\": \"5158d1cfce728efb3e42840d166ec06153a3d77d\", \"features\": [\"audi AtLocation -\", \"audi - ingolstadt\", \"- AtLocation ingolstadt\"], \"end\": \"unite_state\", \"license\": \"/l/CC/By-SA\", \"uri\": \"/a/[AtLocation/,audi/,ingolstadt/]\", \"start\": \"audi\", \"context\": \"/ctx/all\", \"surfaceText\": null}";
        JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonA = (JSONObject) p.parse( a );
        JSONObject jsonB = (JSONObject) p.parse( b );
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        String start = (String) jsonA.get( "start" );
        System.out.println( "Does map contains 'audi' for start:" + map.containsKey( start ) );
        if( !map.containsKey( start ) )
        {
            map.put( start, 1 );
            System.out.println( "Adding to graph" );
        }
        System.out.println( "Does map contains 'audi' for start:" + map.containsKey( start ) );

        start = (String) jsonB.get( "start" );
        if( !map.containsKey( start ) )
        {
            map.put( start, 2 );
            System.out.println( "Adding to graph" );
        }

        System.out.println( "Does map contains 'audi' for start:" + map.containsKey( start ) );
```

The Output that i got:

```
Does map contains 'audi' for start:false
Adding to graph
Does map contains 'audi' for start:true
Does map contains 'audi' for start:true
```

Comment: I have taken as HashMap as <String,Integer> so that you can also save the no of occurrences of "audi" with the key and it might be useful to you later.

Comment: thank you for your reply! Now i understand what is a HashMap for! Came across this but doesnt know how it works! I understand your codes! Cant wait to check it out with my codes in my office tmr morning! Get back to you tmr!

Comment: it has no error, no difference between the previous code and this.. 2 "audi" vertexes were being created..

Comment: it worked for me,you can check your helloGraphDB.addVertex(startV); method then.

Comment: thank you for the help! but again i have knock off! :( Wanted to test out the code desperately but i am in a hurry! let you know again tmr! i thank you sincerely for the help! cheers!

Comment: i have my full codes here! do you mind helping me taking a look? I retrieved the JSON elements dynamically, therefore i am unable to do the comparison by giving one element an variable. Thank you!

Comment: Just add the if conditions from my code to wherever you want things not to be repeated and also make different HashMap for start and end vertex

Comment: can i check if the variable exist before adding them in? is it easier? like start != null those kind? i tried since last week but cannot..

Comment: yes absolutely you can check using map.contain(Key) it returns you true if your element is already present and false if it is not there in the map

Comment: can you help me out? i know is easy but i just cant make it work. ): No error for me to debug somemore.. ): Pleaseeee.. I pasted a code that i tried below this thread, can help me check? Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.infinitegraph.samples.hellograph;

// Import all InfiniteGraph packages
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.infinitegraph.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
// Import SLF4J logging packages
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.infinitegraph.BaseVertex;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HelloGraph
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
                BufferedReader br = null;
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        // Set up logging for the HelloGraph class
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloGraph.class);

        // Create null transaction, null graph database instance
        Transaction tx = null;
        GraphDatabase helloGraphDB = null;

        // Name for graph database and property file
        String graphDbName = "HelloGraph";
        String propertiesFileName = "HelloGraph.properties";    

        try
        {
            try
            {
                // Delete graph database if it already exists
                GraphFactory.delete(graphDbName, propertiesFileName);
            }
            catch (StorageException sE)
            {
                logger.info(sE.getMessage());
            }

            // HINT: Add code to create graph database and its contents
            // Create graph database
            logger.info("> Creating graph database ...");
            GraphFactory.create(graphDbName, propertiesFileName);

            // Open graph database
            logger.info("> Opening graph database ...");
            helloGraphDB = GraphFactory.open(graphDbName, propertiesFileName);

            // Begin transaction
            logger.info("> Starting a read/write transaction ...");
            tx = helloGraphDB.beginTransaction(AccessMode.READ_WRITE);

            //create head vertex
            HeaderVertex head = new HeaderVertex("JSON File");
            helloGraphDB.addVertex(head);

            try {
                String sCurrentLine;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/ji/Desktop/example3.json"));

                HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap <String, Integer>();

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    Object obj;

                    try {
                        obj = parser.parse(sCurrentLine);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

                        //code to create vertex
                        logger.info("> Creating Start vertices ...");     
                        String start = (String) jsonObject.get("start");
                        StartVertex startV = new StartVertex(start);
                        if (!map.containsKey(start))
                        {
                            map.put(start,1);
                            helloGraphDB.addVertex(startV); 
                        }

                        //System.out.println(end);
                        String end = (String) jsonObject.get("end");
                        EndVertex endV = new EndVertex(end);
                        helloGraphDB.addVertex(endV);

                        String rel = (String) jsonObject.get("rel");
                        //System.out.println(rel);
                        logger.info("> Creating Relationship edge ...");
                        Relationship relationship1 = new Relationship("");
                        Relationship relationship2 = new Relationship(rel);

                        // Connect edges
                        logger.info("> Connecting vertices ...");
                        startV.addEdge(relationship1, head, EdgeKind.BIDIRECTIONAL, (short) 0);
                        endV.addEdge(relationship2, startV, EdgeKind.BIDIRECTIONAL, (short) 0);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // Specify a named root for traversal
            logger.info("> Naming a root vertex ...");
            helloGraphDB.nameVertex("JSON File", head);

            // Commit to save your changes to the graph database
            logger.info("> Committing changes ...");
            tx.commit();
        }

        catch (ConfigurationException cE)
        {
            logger.warn("> Configuration Exception was thrown ... ");
            logger.error(cE.getMessage());
        }

        finally
        {
            // If the transaction was not committed, complete
            // will roll it back
            if (tx != null)
                tx.complete();
            if (helloGraphDB != null)
            {
                helloGraphDB.close();
                logger.info("> On Exit: Closed graph database");
            }
        }
    }

}

// HINT: Add class definitions for Person and Meeting classes here.
class HeaderVertex extends BaseVertex
{
    private String header;

    public HeaderVertex (String header)
    {
        setStartName(header);
    }

    public void setStartName (String header)
    {
        markModified();
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        fetch();
        return this.header;
    }
}

class StartVertex extends BaseVertex
{
    private String start;

    public StartVertex (String start)
    {
        setStartName(start);
    }

    public void setStartName (String start)
    {
        markModified();
        this.start = start;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        fetch();
        return this.start;
    }
}

class EndVertex extends BaseVertex
{
    private String end;

    public EndVertex (String end)
    {
        setEndVertex(end);
    }

    public void setEndVertex (String end)
    {
        markModified();
        this.end = end;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        fetch();
        return this.end;
    }
}

class Relationship extends BaseEdge
{
    private String rel;

    public Relationship (String rel)
    {
        setRelationship(rel);
    }

    public void setRelationship (String rel)
    {
        markModified();
        this.rel = rel;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        fetch();
        return this.rel;
    }
}
```

Comment: declare your map variables outside the while loop.
Inside a while loop they will be initialized for every iteration and you will get duplicates.

Comment: I said outside the while loop,its still inside.

Comment: @faizan thank you for the fast reply! i moved it to outside while loop already, now i got an error..

Comment: HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap <String, Integer>();
 have you written outside the loop?

Comment: @faizan i mean thank you for helping me once again..  It is still not working still..  Can you please continue to help me? I really need to make it working.